# Getting error when scripting a command but not when using it manually

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Trying to apply this command :

```
 echo $1 | sed -re 's/.example.com//' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

Manually, it will work (by entering sprod.example.com, i will get "SPROD". But when i'm trying to use it in script, i'll get this :

```
<script_path>: line 34: echo sprod.example.com | sed -re 's/.example.com//' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]': No such file or directory
```

What's the problem ?

## EDIT

Here is my usage of the variable :

```
# uppercase the hostname and cleaning

hostname=$("echo "$1" | sed -re 's/.vdb.local//' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'")

# create the command line to add to the command file
cmdline="[$datetime] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$hostname;$2;$3;$4"
```

Comment: are you sure this is your *exact* line as in the script? No surrounding `"` or anything?

Comment: Is that the whole line, or are you using the result somehow?

Comment: Yes, it's this,
I put the result in a variable and i create a command using this variable

Comment: @NicolasFrbezar So could you show us the whole line?

Comment: The point is that we do not see what you are doing with the output of the line - do you expect it to be echoed on the terminal or is there something around that tries to read it into a variable or something, which is where the error might be?

Comment: i updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong quoting. You have to write it like this:

```
hostname=$(echo "$1" | sed -re 's/.vdb.local//' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```